# Visual Studio 2017 update issue: Unable to load DLL ‘sqlite3’: The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)

Tags: sqlite, visual-studio-2017

While upgrading vs2015 .net standard to vs2017, I got the following error in test project.

> Unable to load DLL ‘sqlite3’: The specified module could not be found.
>   (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)

It works well with vs2015, sqlite provider 1.0.101.0

New Environment: Visual Studio 2017, TargetFramework="net461" using .netcore1.1 packages, sqlite provider 1.0.105.0

I have tried all resolutions I can get from internet as following, but all in vain. I've tried,

1. Added below lines to .csproj,  `<GenerateBindingRedirectsOutputType>true</GenerateBindingRedirectsOutputType><AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>true</AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>`
2. Selected testing processor as x86
3. Installed provider: sqlite-netFx46-static-binary-bundle-Win32-2015-1.0.105.0.zip from [http://system.data.sqlite.org](http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/downloads.wiki)
4. Installed System.Data.SQLite 1.0.105 nuget package
5. Tried put sqlite3.dll (x86) to project folder, set it as "Content" and "copy always", even tried copying the file to bin/x86/, it complains a new error

> An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.
>   (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007000B)

```
at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.Interop.NativeMethods.Sqlite3_sqlite3.sqlite3_open_v2(IntPtr filename, Sqlite3Handle& ppDb, Int32 flags, IntPtr vfs)
   at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.Interop.NativeMethods.Sqlite3_sqlite3.open_v2(IntPtr filename, Sqlite3Handle& ppDb, Int32 flags, IntPtr vfs)
   at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.Interop.NativeMethods.sqlite3_open_v2(String filename, Sqlite3Handle& ppDb, Int32 flags, String vfs)
   at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteConnection.Open()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.Open()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.SqliteRelationalConnection.Open()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable.Enumerator.BufferlessMoveNext(Boolean buffer)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.NoopExecutionStrategy.Execute[TState,TResult](Func`2 operation, Func`2 verifySucceeded, TState state)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ExecutionStrategyExtensions.Execute[TState,TResult](IExecutionStrategy strategy, Func`2 operation, TState state)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable.Enumerator.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryMethodProvider.<_ShapedQuery>d__3`1.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryMethodProvider.<_Include>d__30`1.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryMethodProvider.<_Include>d__30`1.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.LinqOperatorProvider.<_TrackEntities>d__15`2.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.LinqOperatorProvider.ExceptionInterceptor`1.EnumeratorExceptionInterceptor.MoveNext()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at
```

6. Downloaded C++ Runtime for 2017
7. Installed extension of "SQLite runtime for windows"

All doesn't help. 
Anything I missed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solved by a walk-around.

I tried POC in visual studio 2017, with a net461 project and a unit testing project, net461 project works well with sqlite, yet unit testing project needs referencing [sqlite package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/sqlite), 
[image]

Yet, the sqlite package doesn't work well with net461 class library project, no dll is extacted to bin/x86 or bin/x64 folder

[image]

The walk-around is adding x86/sqlite3.dll, x64/sqlite3.dll to project as "Content" and "Copy it Newer" (otherwise, it could be being used, and cause error) as below
[image]
[image]

System.Data.SQLite, is not really needed here.

Now it works. Hope sqlite package will be compatible soon with visual studio 2017